# Phone activated multiple Windows 7 OS with same key

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I have two laptops, bith are using phone activated Windows 7 Ultimate editions, with
with same retail key.

I have their activations backed up using a software.

Could microsoft de-activate one of the laptop's windows (or both) if both of them use internet at the same time?

Comment: Yes;  What you are doing violates the EULA.

Answer (score 5):

You are going against the terms of the EULA

What they can do and what they choose to do is something we can't predict.